# Fork and Threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fork

I am running a program on a machine with a two processors, when I do a fork is the child created as a native thread or it is like a green thread/coroutine. Is the child running concurrently with the parent or it is just parallel?

Comment: This depends on the operating system in question and how you go about creating the process. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, my question goes specific to ruby (Enterprise Edition), I know that it creates fork instances and use green threads to handle multiple requests in parallel, so I wanted to know if I create a fork in a ruby program is it able to run concurrently or it will be treat as a green thread?

Answer (score 8):

The working of fork() in general is to generate a new, independent process, duplicate the page table, and mark all pages owned by the process that called fork() as copy-on-write in that process. Then, fork() returns in both processes (the return value lets the respective process know which one it is).

On a system with more than one processor (or processor cores) you can *normally* (assuming you do have a SMP-enabled system, cpu affinity doesn't prevent it) expect those two processes to use both processors, but you do not strictly have a guarantee.

Threads are generated in the same way on some systems (e.g. Linux) with the exception that the pages owned by the first process are not marked copy-on-write, but are instead owned by both processes afterwards (they use the same page table). On other systems, threads may be implemented differently, e.g. in user land, in which case you will not benefit from multiple cpus with threads.

As a side note, the disadvantage of using fork() and running 2 processes instead of threads is that the processes do not share a common address space, which means that the TLB must be flushed on a context switch.

Comment: They do not share the same address space, a copy is made to the child process, but each process are running on its thread, so I am using threads the only exception is that they do not share address space so I don't need to syncronize acess to mutable stuffs.

Comment: Processes don't share the same address space, that is right (threads do, regardless how they're implemented). Usually, no copy is made to the child process, though. That used to be the case decades ago, but on pretty much every modern system, only the page table is copied and the pages are marked copy on write. The pages are not normally copied (unless one of the processes writes to one later). This is a significant optimization which makes fork much more efficient.

Comment: As for having to synchronize access, you only have to synchronize on memory that the processes generated by fork share, for example memory mapped files etc.

Comment: so if I have a variable xpto and I fork, my child will read the same pointer to xpto unless I try to write on it, then it will be allocate in another space? Thanks for answering I am very grateful.

Comment: Yes, it will be the same value in the same phsyical memory, unless you write to it from one of the processes. That is how for example how redis implements saving a snapshot of the database atomically without interrupting service -- the forked child will do the saving and it has all the time in the world to do that, if the parent modifies a value, the operating system will quickly make a copy to another physical memory location and change the parent's mapping accordingly. Neither of them will know that it has happened. When the child process is done saving, it just terminates.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the operating system, programming-language, compiler and runtime-library, so i can only give you an example: If you use _beginthread under Windows (no matter if you use MinGW or the MSCRT directly) you use both your processors. Further to explain the semantics of "concurrent" vs. "parallel": they are non-exclusive.